# For all files in folder with string in name, add value in cell (2,9) to the end of file name

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Ok, I have many files in a folder that have the string "*$varname*.txt"` in their name:

```
for file in find output/ -name "*$varname*.txt" -type f; do echo $file; done
```

...

now these files all have two lines and 9 columns to them. I want to add the content of line 2, col 9 to the end of their filname (right before the `.txt`).

So I know how to print the value of in cell(2, 9) of all these files:

```
find output/ -name "*$varname*.txt" -type f -exec awk -F' ' 'NR==2{print $9}' {} \;
```

What I struggle with is how to put that string as the last thing before the extension in those filenames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the value and construct the new filename with it.

```sh
find output/ -name "*$varname*.txt" -type f -exec sh -c '
    for file; do
        value=$(awk "NR==2 {print \$9; exit}" "$file")
        echo mv "$file" "${file%.*}$value.${file##*.}"
    done
' sh {} +
```

I'm calling a shell script in the `-exec` directive, passing several filenames to it (with `-exec ... +` instead of `-exec ... \;`)

The trailing "sh" becomes $0, and the filenames go into $1, $2, etc

Comment: I came to the exact same solution, but I’d replace `txt` with `${file##*.}`.

Comment: Why? We are explicitly looking for txt files based on the find command. We already know exactly what the filename extension is.

Comment: Then again, if we change the `-name` pattern, we wouldn't have to *also* change the sh code. Or if the name pattern is dynamic. I see your point

Comment: Exactly – it’s a good thing to make code as universally applicable as possible. Someone searching for “add value to file name” might stumble across this and wonder.

Comment: @user2413 glenn forgot to mention that this only prints what will be done, you need to remove `echo` to perform the renaming, see my answer below where I do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a [GNU `parallel` [image: Install parallel]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parallel) approach:

```bsh
find output/ -name "*$varname*.txt" -type f -print0 |
parallel -0 'echo mv {} {.}$(awk -F" " "NR==2{print\$9}" {}).{=s/.*\.//=}'
```

This pipes the zero-delimited file list to `parallel` which lists the renaming commands – remove `echo` if it does the right thing. `parallel` comes with handy replacement strings, `{}` is replaced by the (currently processed) input file name, `{.}` by the input filename without extension and with `{=perl expression=}` you can run anything `perl` can do, like a substitution here. The output of your `awk` command is simply added using [Command Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. In this case, this  is part of a `bash` function that will itself be called by `parallel` (so in my individual use case it is a bit moot hence my awarding the points to @glenn jackman's answer) but I'm sure other reader will appreciate doing these sort of tasks 8 times faster!